# How to move utility sink and extend trap / drain pipe under it?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I'd like to move the utility sink (that my washer drains into) in my basement ~6 inches to the left to accommodate a new washer dryer.

The incoming water lines aren't a problem, but as you can see from the image below, the drain goes straight down to a trap and then back 90 degrees to the house drain.

My question is: if I move the sink to the left should I build with a couple of elbows and a straight section  from the house drain side and connect to the trap or is there any kind of "extra long trap" I should be looking at instead?

If it makes any difference, I'm in Montgomery County, Maryland.

Thanks!

[image: underneath utility sink]

Answer (score 2):

You would do well to incorporate an elbow or elbows, if possible into the part of the drain line that is behind the white PVC pipe, the metal pipe. The trouble with that would be is that old of pipe is easily damaged (broken) at the joints where the threaded sections are.

The reason I suggest this as the place to tie in the new extension is that by the time, I feel, if you simply replace the drain it will be so far away from the wall it will be a number of inches away from the wall it is against now. To remedy that, it would take so may elbows to get it back to the wall, I am afraid the drain would not drain readily or perhaps clog easily. So back at the reason why I mentioned taking it back and tying it into the farther in from the joint where it is tied in now. The place I refer to is at the wye, there is a small straight pipe there, perhaps there is a smooth part (no threads) to it to use a neoprene coupler there.

Comment: I had to rethink this a bit. There is a chance that if you did replace only the existing PVC, the J bend may simply pass behind the pipe instead of in front of the pipe like it is now... The J bend gives a lot of leniency on how pipes are oriented to each other.